# How node.js can help in WebOS or HTML5 development

Tags: node.js

I just read about node.js and I really don't have any idea about the same. 
So I just want to know that will node.js will help me somewhere in HTML 5 and WebOS based development and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through http://nodebeginner.org, it should set you straight on what node is.